# Unable to find the right iOS DateFormatter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

In my app I am getting date string from server like that "2019-12-30 21:25:06" so I am using the formatter like "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Then I want to change the date for mat to "Dec 30, 2019" so I change the format to "MMM dd, yyyy" but it doesn't work.

Here I using "https://nsdateformatter.com/" and using the formatter "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" means the date will changed from "2019-12-30 21:25:06" to "2019-12-30 15:55:06", I can't find the reason.

Here I mention my code for date formatter.

```
let createdDateString:String = "2019-12-30 21:25:06"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let dateOrder = dateFormatter.date(from: createdDateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
let orderDateStr:String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateOrder!)
dateLbl.text = orderDateStr
```

Comment: I tried your code I am not faced any issues,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik But for Me app crashed in this line let orderDateStr:String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateOrder!)

Comment: @B.SaravanaKumar your app is crashed because you use force unwrapping for `dateOrder`. Better use optional chaining (as example) and are you sure that you have expected date format from server?

Comment: add         dateFormatter.locale =  Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
and check

Comment: Your above code seems to work fine for me

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, now its working after adding Locale..Thanks bro.

Comment: @B.SaravanaKumar - actually its recently happens in ios 13.3 devices